# How to build Alljoyn standard core v15.09a

Tags: linux, iot, alljoyn

I downloaded the AJ standard core and attempted to build it. The instructions given in the page at the link [Alljoyn Building Linux](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/building/linux) (https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/building/linux) does not match the directory structure of the package downloaded. The instruction says that the directory should look like this:
root-source-dir/
core/
  --  alljoyn/
  --  ajtcl/
services/
  --  base/
  --  base_tcl/

However, the package's directory structure is quite different as follows:
usr1@Ubuntu14p4LTS-HP1001:~/workspace/alljoyn/alljoyn-15.09.00a-src$
 
    drwxr-xr-x  8 usr1 usr1 4096 Nov 12 14:14 alljoyn_c 
    drwxr-xr-x 10 usr1 usr1 4096 Nov 12 14:14 alljoyn_core
    drwxr-xr-x  9 usr1 usr1 4096 Nov 12 14:14 alljoyn_java
    drwxr-xr-x  9 usr1 usr1 4096 Nov 12 14:14 alljoyn_js
    drwxr-xr-x  8 usr1 usr1 4096 Nov 12 14:14 alljoyn_objc
    drwxr-xr-x  4 usr1 usr1 4096 Nov 12 14:14 build_core
    -rw-r--r--  1 usr1 usr1 3485 Nov 12 14:14 build.xml
    drwxr-xr-x  7 usr1 usr1 4096 Nov 12 14:14 common
    drwxr-xr-x  4 usr1 usr1 4096 Nov 12 14:14 external
    -rw-r--r--  1 usr1 usr1  102 Nov 12 14:14 manifest.txt
    -rw-r--r--  1 usr1 usr1 1363 Nov 12 14:14 README.md
    -rw-r--r--  1 usr1 usr1  372 Nov 12 14:14 README.txt
    -rw-r--r--  1 usr1 usr1 3996 Nov 12 14:14 SConstruct
    drwxr-xr-x  3 usr1 usr1 4096 Nov 12 14:14 services
    -rw-r--r--  1 usr1 usr1   38 Nov 12 14:14 tsan.supp

Also, the README.txt file from the root (alljoyn-15.09.00a-src) refer to these two files for build instructions but unfortunately, they cannot be found at the location given: "**Build instructions** are found in: `alljoyn_core/docs/BUILD.txt` (there is also and HTML version available in the directory)."

I think that missing are the build instructions README.txt and the SConstruct file specific to Alljoyn standard core v15.09a. I found the ones for v14.06.00a which I tried to extrapolate and use with 15.09a. I was able to get partially through but then quickly ran into some other build issues downstream due to some mismatch in the header files and cpp files.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help . Please read. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In order to build Aj Standard Core with services, you should fetch the sources of both core and services project.

In order to the defaults work, the folder structure should be something like;

```
.
├── core
│   ├── ajtcl //Thin Core
│   └── alljoyn // Standard Core
└── services
    ├── base // Standard Services
    ├── base_tcl //Thin Services
```

Fetch the corresponding projects from [git.allseeenalliance.com](https://git.allseenalliance.org/cgit/) If you just want to build the standard core with services than the `alljoyn` and `base` projects are enough to build.

After the fetching completed, go to the alljoyn directory and type for building the standard core.

```
scons BINDINGS=cpp WS=off BR=off ICE=off VARIANT=debug NDEBUG=undefined SERVICES="about,notification,controlpanel,config,onboarding,sample_apps"
```

If you are curious about the build options, just follow the [link.](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/building/linux/build-source)

Comment: Thanks Fatih. I will give those links a try and follow your suggestion.